# How to browse using python?

Tags: python, import, operating-system

**import os**

**os.system('chrome sololearn')**

#Chrome searches sololearn/
#I want Chrome to search sololearn

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to give us a more comprehensible question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Selenium and automate google search
first install selenium in your idle or pycharm
Selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

install

Chromedriver

Download the chrome browser from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) (choose the version for your system)
After downloading, extract it and then copy the file in the folder of the script.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

# Taking input from user 
search_string = input("Input the URL or string you want to search for:") 

# This is done to structure the string  
search_string = search_string.replace(' ', '+') 

# Assigning the browser variable with chromedriver of Chrome.
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver') 

for i in range(1): 
    matched_elements = browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
                                    search_string + "&start=" + str(i))
```